# Firebase Authentication Costing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Does updating user details such as **name, password or adding/deleting Custom Claims** in firebase authentication also cost charge ?

Suppose if I have 1 million users in my app with using firebase authentication and if I update password of all the users or add custom claims to all the user using firebase Admin SDK. Does this process cost any charge ?

Answer (score 2):

> Does updating user details such as name, password or adding/deleting Custom Claims in firebase authentication also cost charge ?

No.

> Suppose if I have 1 million users in my app with using firebase authentication and if I update password of all the users or add custom claims to all the user using firebase Admin SDK. Does this process cost any charge ?

No.

I suggest reviewing the pricing information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).  Firebase Auth has no charges except for phone auth.  What you are describing is covered by "Other Authentication services" which are not billed.

There are [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#api_limits) to the rate at which you may make API calls, which you should also review.

If you have further questions about billing that are not covered in the documentation, you should send those directly to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).